# wp_enqueue not working at all

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to create a wordpress theme and start learning the best way to include javascript and css files using wp_enqueue. After couple hours, I still can't load the files. Here is the code I use

```
function compro_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/materialize.css', array(), '20150208', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'style' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'compro_scripts' );
```

It looked simple on every tutorial I've read, but it still not work for me. Would anyone mind helping me solve this ?

Comment: Do you have `wp_head()` in the head and `wp_footer()` in the footer

Comment: OMG, thank you Pieter. That's what I've been missing, I just found out the importance of these hook. Thank you for helping this newbie :)

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very basic knowledge of Wordpress, but as a newbie I found out this is pretty confusing. If you want to use the best practice to include javascript and css files make sure to add `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`. The rest of it is described clearly here [How to Load Javascript like Wordpress Master](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html)

Answer (score 1):

You've registered the "style" handle with [wp_register_style()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) and you're enqueuing it by using [wp_enqueue_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) which is incorrect. wp_enqueue_script() in your code needs to be replaced by [wp_enqueue_style()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style), since it's a style that you are including, not a script.

Alternatively, you can simply enqueue scripts and styles directly without the need to register them separately - like this

```
function compro_scripts() {
    $template_dir = get_template_directory_uri();

    //enqueue a style
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', $template_dir . '/css/materialize.css', array(), '20150208', 'all');

    //enqueue a script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', $template_dir . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'compro_scripts' );
```